# Does ‘took a long time to send them’ express ‘he didn’t send them’？

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions

I see a sentence in my book:

> Editors of newspapers and magazines often go to extremes to provide their readers with unimportant facts and statistics. Last year a journalist had been instructed by a well-known magazine to write an article on the president's palace in a new African republic. When the article arrived, the editor read the first sentence and then refused to publish it. The article began: 'Hundreds of steps lead to the high wall which surrounds the president's palace.' The editor at once sent the journalist a telegram instructing him to find out the exact number of steps and the height of the wall.

> The journalist immediately set out to obtain these important facts, **but he took a long time to send them**. *Meanwhile, the editor was getting impatient, for the magazine would soon go to press.* He sent the journalist two more faxes, but received no reply. He sent yet another fax informing the journalist that if he did not reply soon he would be fired. When the journalist again failed to reply, the editor reluctantly published the article as it had originally been written. A week later, the editor at last received a telegram from the journalist. Not only had the poor man been arrested, but he had been sent to prison as well. However, he had at last been allowed to send a fax in which he informed the editor that he had been arrested while counting the 1,084 steps leading to the fifteen-foot wall which surrounded the president's palace.

So, we can guess that the journalist didn’t send important facts to the editor. But why **took a long time to send them** expresses as **didn’t send them**？

If I want to express that I took a long time and finally sent them, what should I write？

Comment: You haven't given enough context to conclude that they were never sent. Just that in the "meanwhile" sentence, they hadn't been sent yet.

Comment: @DanGetz  I modified my context and there is enough context. Thanks!

Comment: So funnily enough, he did finally send them, a week later. A week earlier, he just had not sent them yet.

Comment: @DanGetz  But does the sentence ‘he took a long time to send them’ express that ‘he didn’t send them’？ ‘Meanwhile’ follows ‘he took a long time to send them’. Based on this, ‘he took a long time to send them’ expresses that ‘he didn’t send them’. Am I right？

Comment: From the point of view of the waiting editor, the journalist _was taking a long time_ to send the information. The editor was still hoping that it would eventually arrive!

Comment: @KateBunting  We can’t judge whether he had sent the information from the phrases ‘he took a long time to send them’. Am I right？

Comment: Normally, 'he took a long time to do [something]' means that he did it, but much later than expected. It would not usually be used if the task was not done at all. That is why I suggested that the sentence in your book was written from the editor's point of view while he was still waiting.

Comment: I think only a sloppy writer / speaker would use ***he took a long time to do it*** in a context where he didn't in fact do it at all. But some people are sloppy thinkers, so I'm sure it happens sometimes. On the other hand, I've no problem with ***he took too long to do it*** being used regardless of whether he eventually did it or not.

Comment: @KateBunting  But why that followed by ** Meanwhile, the editor was getting impatient…**？  So if he sent them, there states that the editor was waiting, which is a little weird.

Comment: I said in my last comment that it was _unusual_ for the expression to be used when the task had not been done. As FF says, it's sloppy writing.

Comment: May you tell me what does **FF** stand for?

Comment: I was referring to the previous comment by FumbleFingers.